# Logging in the User and loading his data

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore, database-design, swiftui, firebase-authentication

After User logs in, don't understand how to proceed further into the app, fetch/represent his info and also start to populate it.
In my case user registered only with email and password, no additional information.

As in the pictures below, `Authentication` and `Firestore` look like separate things

2. (Optional) Further I want to understand how to save other posts and subscribe to users.

registration ViewModel

```
import Firebase

class RegisterViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var email: String = ""
    var password: String = ""

    func register(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
               print("registered successfully")
               completion()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

login ViewModel

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var email: String = ""
    var password: String = ""

    func login(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
        
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                print("logged in successfully")
                completion()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe some directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways of doing so. Certain information is saveable in the user or Authentication. Like [username](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#update_a_users_profile), [phone number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth) or [photo url](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start#get_user_information).

I usually used the users [ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start#get_user_information) `user.uid` , which is unique, to add a document for the user to a collection containing all users. There you can save all the additional information easily. Like friends requests, friends, posts, urls to pictures etc.

So for your question: Ask the user to enter a username and other additional information at either the point he's creating the account or on the first login. Or just make the options available to add them in the user profile.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I found that I create user, but don't create document for him, so there's no reference for this user in actual firestore database.